# The topology of a $k$-dimensional ball in $\mathbb R^N$ and the definition of attaching a $k$-cell

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, algebraic-topology, morse-theory

Let $B_k$ be the $k$-dimensional ball in $\mathbb R^N$:
$$
B_k = \left\{x \in \mathbb R^N \ : \ \sum_{i = 1}^k x_i^2 < 1, \ x_{k + 1} = \ldots = x_N = 0 \right\}.
$$
In the context of Morse Theory, it is called a *$k$-cell*.

The operation of attaching a $k$-cell to a topological space $Y$ is defined in my book (*Morse Index of Solutions of Nonlinear Elliptic Equations*, Damascelli and Pacella, 2019) as follows:

Take a continuous function $g: \overline{\partial B_k} \to Y$ which is homeomorphic to its image. The topological space obtained by taking the union of $Y$ and the closed $k$-cell $\overline{B_k}$ with the equivalence relation which identifies $x \in \overline{\partial B_k}$ with its image $g(x) \in Y$ will be denoted by $Y \cup_g B_k$ ($Y$ with a $k$-cell attached).

Milnor, in his classical book, takes $g$ defined on $S^{k - 1}$

My questions are:

> What is $\overline{\partial B_k}$, and why do we take it as the domain of $g$?

For the first part, as I understand, $\overline{\partial B_k} = \overline{B_k}$. Indeed, the boundary is obtained by taking the closure and excluding the interior. But the interior of $\overline{B_k}$ is empty. What am I missing?

> What does it mean to take the equivalence relation $x \sim g(x)$ in $Y \cup_g B_k$? Intuitively, what are we doing?

I'm quite clueless about this.

Comment: It must be a typo and should be read as $\partial B_k$. Do you know about quotient topology?

Comment: But even then, isn't $\partial B_k = \overline{B_k}$? And I know about the quotient topology, but my difficulty is to realize what happens to the guys in $Y$ who are not associated to any $x$, that is, outside the image of $g$.

Comment: There are two different notions of boundary in topology: The one you are thinking about is from General Topology and is a wrong thing to use. The right notion of the boundary here is the boundary of the closed ball regarded as a manifold with boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is all what the authors say, it is poor notation.

1. One should emphasize that $B_k$ is topologically an *open ball*. But note that it is not an open subset of $\mathbb R^N$ unless $N = k$. Anyway, the closure $\overline{B_k}$ in $\mathbb R^N$ is always topologically a closed $k$-dimensional ball.
2. They authors do not define $\partial B_k$.
3. For $N > k$ the interpretation of $\partial B_k$ as the topological boundary of $B_k$ in $\mathbb R^N$ produces in fact $\partial B_k = \overline{B_k}$. Only for $N = k$ we get $\partial B_k = \overline{B_k} \setminus B_k$.
4. An interpretation of $\partial B_k$ which depends on $N$ does not make sense. Therefore the only reasonable interpretation is $\partial B_k = \overline{B_k} \setminus B_k$. But then $\partial B_k$ is closed and $ \overline{\partial B_k} = \partial B_k$. So it remains open why the authors write $\overline{\partial B_k}$. Anyway, $\partial B_k \approx S^{k-1}$. This agrees with Milnor.
5. The notation $Y \cup_g B_k$ is unusual because $g$ is defined on $\partial B_k$ which is disjoint from $B_k$. The standard notation is $Y \cup_g  \overline{B_k}$

Comment: Dear Paul, thanks for the answer, it has clarified very well the first of my doubts. But how to make sense of this equivalence relation they define? What happens to the guys outside the image of $g$?

Comment: $Y \cup_g \overline{B_k}$ (my notation!) is a quotient space of the disjoint union $Y + \overline{B_k}$ in which each $x \in \partial B_k$ is identified with $g(x) \in Y$. The quotient map $p: Y + overline{B_k} \to Y \cup_g \overline{B_k}$ maps $B_k$ *'homeomorphically* onto $B'_k = g(B_k)$. Thus $B'_k$ is a subspace of $Y \cup_g \overline{B_k}$ which is topologically an open $k$-cell. Consider an example: $Y$ = one-point space; then  $Y \cup_g \overline{B_k} \approx S^k$.

Comment: Regarding the example: It makes total sense that identifying the boundary of a ball with a point gives a sphere in one more dimension. However, shouldn't the map $g: S^{k - 1}$ be an homeomorphism to its image? How can this be, in this case?

Comment: @DaniloGregorinAfonso The construction itself does not have any restriction concerning $g$. It may be an embedding or not.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, Milnor doesn't require the homeomorphism condition, but my book does, as do Ambrosetti and Malchiodi in *Nonlinear Analysis and Semilinear Elliptic Problems*. I will ask the authors why do they do it. Anyway, all is clear now, and I thank you again